# How can I add ng-zorro-antd?

Tags: angular, antd, ng-zorro-antd

I'm trying to create an ng-zorro project using Angular.
I have tried these commands:

```
npm install --location=global @angular/cli
ng new ng-zorro-demo
```

I have created an Angular project with routing.

```
cd ng-zorro-demo/
ng add ng-zorro-antd
```

After the latest command I got an error:

```
rom@rom-lenovo:~/WebstormProjects/ng-zorro-demo$ ng add ng-zorro-antd
Skipping installation: Package already installed
? Enable icon dynamic loading [ Detail: https://ng.ant.design/components/icon/en ] Yes
? Set up custom theme file [ Detail: https://ng.ant.design/docs/customize-theme/en ] Yes
? Choose your locale code: en_US
? Choose template to create project: sidemenu
Could not find project in workspace: undefined
```

I can launch the project with ng serve. It works, so I don't understand why ng-zorro reports it is no project there. When I choose the template _blank it works perfectly.

Comment: What about your Angular & Ng-Zorro versions?

Comment: They are compatible. I verified. Even if they were incompatible my project with _blank template would not start.

Comment: Latest version of Angular is 14 but Ng-Zorro is not updated for 14 for example. Versions that you don't say can be still an issue. Global Angular, Local Angular, CLI & Zorro.

Comment: I reinstalled Angular with version 13. It works perfect. Thanks a lot for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

What is the angular version you are using?
If you angular version 14.0.0, you have to downgrade the angular version.
Because now supports Angular ^13.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I would say try installing it via npm since you already tried to do  it with the @angular/cli install and that gave you errors.  The docs for ng ant design say you can try

```
npm install ng-zorro-antd
```

Is it showing in your packages ?

Comment: I've tried to do this. All necessary packages have been installed, but the option Sidebar still doesn't work. Maybe there is a bug of ng-zorro.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem.
It is related to the versioning issue. please follow the link for the solution.

[Getting error when adding "add ng-zorro-antd" to Project with Angular CLI: 14.0.4 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72864845/getting-error-when-adding-add-ng-zorro-antd-to-project-with-angular-cli-14-0/72951671#72951671)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install ng-zorro-antd in your project then try this command:

`npm install ng-zorro-antd --save`

it will work.